# How to avoid init_per_suite and end_per_suite to be counted as test cases in Common Test?

Tags: erlang, common-test

I have a test suite which has the init and end functions implemented in it.

When I run the suite it produces some html outputs to show the results of the test cases (pass and fail etc.) from the suite.

But in the log the `init_per_suite` and `end_per_suite` are also counted as test cases and their run result is shown in the log. Is there a way to avoid this? I guess there might be a flag in Erlang common test which can be used to disable this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't disable it. Besides it may be important information if start_per_suite/end_per_suite succeeds or or fails.
Also you can see that start_per_suite/end_per_suite are not included in general numeration of testcases in resulting html. May be it'll help you if you want to parse the html output. Also you can sort cases by their numbers so the unnumered cases will be on the top/bottom.